# On hover of menu the block is not displayed in safari 8

Tags: html, css, safari

```css
#social-left {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  width: 124px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 100;
}
#slideout_inner a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#social-left:hover {
  right: 168px;
}
#social-left:hover #slideout_inner {
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}
#slideout_inner {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  right: -250px;
  width: 167px;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social-left">

  <!--<img src="images/menu2.png">-->
  <div style="border: 2px solid #fff ;color: #fff;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;padding-left: 1px;">
    <span style="border: 2px solid #41A7B7;background:#41A7B7;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;padding: 0px 35px 0px 35px;font-weight:bold">Menu</span>
  </div>

  <div id="slideout_inner" class="" style="position: fixed;font-size:15px">
    <div style='background:#41A7B7;border:2px solid #41A7B7;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;padding-right:10px'>
      <a href="#header-wrapper">Home</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#about-Matthew-Howard">About</a> 
      <br>
      <a href="#the-system">The System</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#how-and-why-it-works">How & Why It Works</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#future-health-of-india">Future Health Of India</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#contact-us">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

On hover of the div `#social-left` the menu section displays the div `#slideout_inner`.
This works in all the browsers. The problem is in  safari 8 in OS X Yosemite,the slideout_inner block is not displayed.
Please help

Comment: Tested on safari 8 in OS X Yosemite the slideout_inner_block is displaying for me.

Comment: actually its not working for the website I am working on. Due to company policy cannot share the url of the website. Its a parralax website and the block is displayed when clicked from the 3rd <section> onwards.

Comment: It must be something else on the website that is causing this issue, as the code on its own is fine.

Comment: I checked the code by commenting and found it. I have used bxslider in the website which is causing the issue. Can I add anything in the bxslider function which will remove the issue in Safari. Please  help.

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the full code I'm not sure I can help you further.

Comment: Ok. Anyways thanks Chris